# Shopping basket rounding

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, e-commerce

I'm trying to find the best way to calculate basket's prices and totals.
All product prices are represented by figures with 2 decimal points, however, when discount is added to the basket of say 50%, this given for instance price of $37.27 ends up with figure $18.635 having 3 decimal places. Now I'd like the calculations to be accurate, but rounding 3 decimal figures doesn't always give the expected result.

**Scenario**

I have 5 products in my basket with the following, original prices:

- $80.00
- $189.62
- $37.27
- $43.75
- $105.34

Giving us total of `$455.98`

When I add a global discount of 50% - taking the total of figures above, this would give me `$227.99`. Now, this would work fine if I don't have to obtain the figure for each item after the discount has been applied - and that is the case when I want to pass the items to the PayPal Express Checkout. Request will fail unless total equals total of all items in the basket.

The above figures after dividing each by 2 (50%) are:

- $40.00
- $94.81
- $18.635
- $21.875
- $52.67

Giving us precisely same total as when we divide the total by 2.
Problem is that I do not want 3 decimal figures in my basket, so rounding them the result becomes:

- $40.00
- $94.81
- $18.64
- $21.88
- $52.67

which adds up to `$228`, which when multiplied by 2 gives us a different figure to the one we originally had in the basket without discount being applied.

What is the best way to tackle this sort of scenarios?

Comment: Do not calculate with rounded numbers... Keep the originals numbers and calculate with those..

Comment: Well that's not always an option when you can only show 2 decimals on the site.

Comment: To answer the broader question: either calculate the price after discount the second way, and show that to the customer `"Total after discount: $288.00"` Or just send paypal a single object with an orderid and associated cost - there is no specific need to detail every product

Comment: I assume there is a protocol for that which describes how such things must be handled. If you must calculate each discount separately, then do so and then sum the dicsounted values. Otherwise, calculate it over the overall sum.

Comment: @Steve - that's what I thought of doing originally, but thought it might be nice for the client to see what they are actually agreeing to buying on PayPals portal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - it's going to be either or - what I want to have is the basket that's accurate so it might be best if I simply round figures and then calculate total based on it - it's discount that causes it and I don't think 0.01 is going to make a big difference to anyone buying online.

Comment: @seb You would be suprised how many people would actually fall over 0.01, especially if the webshop is for bussiness users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is such a great question. my vote would be to apply the 50% discount to each item - round that number to 2 decimal places with number format - and save that number as part of the cart order record even if you aren't showing to customer. then add those figures up like normal to get the cart product total.

reason: someone at some point is going to need a clear amount that was charged for each product. AND think about returns. its going to make returns so much easier if you aren't having to correct for .01 differences.

Comment: Thanks @cartalot - what I ended up doing eventually was to run each product through a discount percentage and rounding the output of each one to 2 decimal points. After that I got the subtotals off of the discounted products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bcmul()`, it will make sure your numbers are precise.

When you want to make sure the prices always have two decimal points, you can use `number_format()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmul.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: I'm using number_format() with two decimal places and that's what's causing the actual problem. I'll have a look at bcmul() and see what result I'll get out of it.

Comment: Well, generally you'd use `number_format` only after the math has been applied, as a means to make sure it has 2 decimals, since `10.1` (for example) will not have a trailing zero.

Comment: I've tried `bcdiv` to divide given figure by 2 (50%), but that just cuts the third decimal without actually rounding it at all - so at the end I'm getting the result lower than the original so not quite the set of functions for what I'm after. I don't think there is any way other than letting it keep more decimal places or simply get total after all subsequent products had their price rounded after discount.

Comment: If all you're looking for is controlled rounding, `round()` has a parameter that allows you to set the mode. Eg, `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Using `round()` with the mode flags gives the same result. Whatever I use it's just always going to either go up or down by `$0.01`

Comment: Well, if you're applying discounts to products, then summing them together *after* having rounded each figure, you're going to end up with "incorrect" (in quotes) prices. It really comes down to the business logic you have. Either you round before, or after, but that's up to your business logic.